# formatting string - remove leading numbers

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-2.0, xpath-2.0

I'm trying to remove leading chapter numbers via XPath functions from strings, which look like this

```
<heading>3 Some Heading</heading>
<heading>5.2 some Heading 4 Something</heading>
<heading>Another One</heading>
<heading>For good Measure 2</heading>
```

and my desired output would look like this

```
<heading>Some Heading</heading>
<heading>some Heading 4 Something</heading>
<heading>Another One</heading>
<heading>For good Measure 2</heading>
```

So far I've tried *translate()* and *string-after()*, but the numbers inside or to the end of the string are killing me.
I'm grateful for every help!

Comment: See a pure XSLT 1.0 solution -- no need to learn XPath 2.0 RegEx for this problem :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `replace`, if you are really using XSLT 2.0

```
<xsl:template match="heading">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:value-of select="replace(., '^[\s.\d]+', '')"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: nailed it, thanks! Still not so familiar with xslt 2.0 functions.

Answer (score 1):

**Here is a pure XSLT 1.0 solution** (also producing the correct result with an XSLT 2.0 processor):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match=
        "text()[number(translate(substring-before(., ' '), '.', '')) 
              = number(translate(substring-before(., ' '), '.', ''))]">
    <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(., ' ')"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

**A pure XSLT 2.0 solution that doesn't use RegEx**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match=
    "text()[translate(substring-before(., ' '), '.', '') castable as xs:integer]">
    <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(., ' ')"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When any of the above transformations is applied on the following XML document:**

```
<t>
    <heading>3 Some Heading</heading>
    <heading>5.2.1 some Heading 4 Something</heading>
    <heading>Another One</heading>
    <heading>For good Measure 2</heading>
    <heading>NoSpace</heading>
</t>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<t>
   <heading>Some Heading</heading>
   <heading>some Heading 4 Something</heading>
   <heading>Another One</heading>
   <heading>For good Measure 2</heading>
   <heading>NoSpace</heading>
</t>
```

Comment: You are assuming `5.2.1` cannot exist.

Comment: @michael.hor257k, Thank you, I was misled by the word "numbers" in the question. Of course, this is easy to fix -- just a minute

Comment: @michael.hor257k, `5.2.1` is now processed correctly.